# Erro ao enviar formulário para gravar

Tags: php

Está gerando o seguinte erro ao enviar meu formulário para gravar: Notice: Undefined index: cliente in C:\xampp\htdocs\guaraparivirtual\adm-gc\gravar-texto.php on line 3

Este código abaixo `$idcli = $_GET['cliente'];` é o código do cliente que recebo de outra página antes de chegar até aqui. O próximo código também precisa receber este parâmetro para gravar os dados pra o cliente correto, e é aí que gera o erro, pois este parâmetro é repassado pela `action` do formulário.

**Página do formulário:**

```
<?php
$idcli = $_GET['cliente'];
?>
<?php
$painel=mysqli_query($con,"select detalhe_sobre from anuncios where id = '$idcli'");
while($painel_texto=mysqli_fetch_array($painel)){
$texto_empresa = $painel_texto['detalhe_sobre'];
}
?>
<form class="frm-adm-painel" action="gravar-texto.php?cliente=<?php echo $idcli; ?>">
    <textarea name="textoempresarial" rows="10" placeholder="Texto sobre a Empresa">
    <?php echo utf8_encode(strip_tags(nl2br($texto_empresa)));  ?>
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit">GRAVAR</button>
</form>
```

**Página que gera o erro:**

A linha que gera o erro é esta: `$idcli = $_GET['cliente'];`

```
<?php
$idcli = $_GET['cliente'];
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "Gravado com sucesso";
}
?>
```

Comment: Duplicada? No outro posto não mostra algo que corrija o erro dado comigo! Lá é outra situação totalmente diferente.

Comment: É o mesmo problema, na primeira chamada da sua página `$_GET['cliente']` não existe logo era o undefined index, vc precisa verificar se ele existe e tem valor (pode ser com o `empty()`), também precisa pular o bloco da consulta caso ele não exista. pq não envia o id via post?

Comment: Como eu faria o envio via post?

Comment: Cria um input hidden mesmo assim vai precisar da lógica do comentário anterior. Pode deixar essa sugestão para o final.